# Azure Functions local HTTP trigger issue and solution

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, nvm

Just wanted to post the steps I took after running into the following error when trying to run an Azure Function HTTP Trigger locally in VS Code:

```
"[error] Incompatible Node.js version. The version you are using is v13.1.0, 
 but the runtime requires an LTS-covered major version. LTS-covered versions 
 have an even major version number (8.x, 10.x, etc.) as per 
 https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-plan. For deployed code, change 
 WEBSITENODEDEFAULT_VERSION to '~10' in App Settings. Locally, install or 
 switch to a supported node version (make sure to quit and restart your code 
 editor to pick up the changes)."
```

Answer (score 2):

(1.) install NVM. Instructions here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

(2.) install NVS. Instructions here: https://github.com/jasongin/nvs

(3.) in your VS code terminal, run:

```
nvs add 12.16.1
nvs use node/12.16.1/x64
```

(4.) edit your launch.json to the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5555,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ],
    "node": {
        "runtimeVersion": "12.16.1"
    }
}
```

(5.) in your VS code terminal, run:

```
func start
```

Comment: What if I want to debug it?